# How to position the clicked image in a div to the horizontal center of the viewport?

Tags: jquery, html, center, viewport

I have a flex div containing 7 images in one row. At the initial state, only the first five images are in the viewport, with the third image being at the horizontal center. When one of the images is clicked, it needs to be moved to the horizontal center of the viewport and the remaining images should be repositioned accordingly. How could this be implemented with jquery or javascript?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards.

Comment: Are you trying to make a gallery of images and each image the user clicks on gets bigger and in the center of the page right?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by implementing 7 overlapping flex divs with different left margins. Then displayed the corresponding div, and updated its margin-left value with the swipe-left and swipe-right events.
Thank you.